# Magento: Creating an event to extend customer creation in magento

Tags: magento, observers

So I am simply trying to create a hook into registrations predispatch event. This is what I have so far:

```
config.xml:

<events>
  <controller_action_predispatch_customer_account_createpost>
    <observers>
      <mymodulename>
        <class>mymodulename/observer</class>
        <method>hookToAccountCreationBefore</method>
      </mymodulename>
    </observers>
  </controller_action_predispatch_customer_account_createpost>
</events>
```

and the observer:

```
Model/Observer.php :

public function hookToAccountCreationBefore($observer) {
  die('getting here');
}
```

So I go and do a registration and I see the controller_action_predispatch_customer_account_createpost event getting called in my event logs but its not calling my function.

Please help!

UPDATE:

The answer below worked perfectly for me. However, $observer->getEvent()->getCustomer() is getting NULL for me even though another observer is overriding the same exact event and this works fine. I've tried temporarily commenting out the observer config for the other extension and its still empty. Any ideas?

Comment: In your observer you can't get objects that were not dispatched with the event. `controller_action_predispatch_` events are triggered during the application dispatching (obviously) and do not contain any objects from contoller logic implementation. From this event you can get only action controller itself. You should use another event to get customer upon creation - like `customer_register_success`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your config.xml you could also do

```
config.xml:

<global>
    <models>
        <mymodulename>
            <class>MyNamespace_MyModuleName_Model</class>
        </mymodulename>
    </models>
    <events>
        <controller_action_predispatch_customer_account_createpost>
            <observers>
                <mymodulename>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>mymodulename/observer</class>
                    <method>hookToAccountCreationBefore</method>
                </mymodulename>
            </observers>
        </controller_action_predispatch_customer_account_createpost>
    </events>
</global>
```

or

```
<global>
    <events>
        <controller_action_predispatch_customer_account_createpost>
            <observers>
                <mymodulename>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>MyNamespace_MyModuleName_Model_Observer</class>
                    <method>hookToAccountCreationBefore</method>
                </mymodulename>
            </observers>
        </controller_action_predispatch_customer_account_createpost>
    </events>
</global>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe  try  with  following  Event

```
customer_register_success
```